# Save WordPress plugin settings with form

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i have this wordpress project and my script runs well and saved the into the database. My problem is when i insert the value `zipcode 2034` and refresh the wp-admin page i think the data is being saved, now i want to input another `zipcode 6000` and the first input value is being replaced with the new one. How ill i able to insert another value from it ? without replacing the saved data. Here is my code below

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'zipcode_menu');

function zipcode_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Zipcode Page', 'Zipcode', 'manage_options', 'zipcode', 'zipcode' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'update_extra_post_info' );

function update_extra_post_info() {
    register_setting( 'extra-post-info-settings', 'zipcode' );

}

function zipcode() {


    // Now display the settings editing screen

    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    // header
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Zipcode', 'zip' ) . "</h2>";
    // settings form
    $extra_info = get_option('zipcode');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($extra_info);
    echo "</pre>";

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'extra-post-info-settings' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'extra-post-info-settings' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Zipcode:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" value="<?php echo get_option( 'zipcode' ); ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <table width="600px">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Zipcode
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <?php

}
```

and i want to retrieve all the saved data from the database into the `table` Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreicated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress `register_setting` do the registration in table `wp_options` so
it will always replace the value of your option. So i suggest create a new table and manager your zip code from this table.

Comment: ahh okay so you mean i will to create my own table then save the data that im creating yes?

Comment: so in register_setting that will always replace the value hmmmm

Comment: Yes by default register_setting it will save the data into the option_name in the same table and you need an id for each zipcode so you can't do this in wp_options